# Change default CAMERA LENS on ANDROID

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

How can I change the default lens on my Android device?

I want the device to use my ULTRA-WIDE LENS instead of the default one when opening apps like Instagram, since I feel it is very ZOOM even if it is at 1x.

I have a Xiaomi Redmi Note 12 with Android 13 & MIUI 14

I did not find any solution on the internet and Xiaomi support has not given me any solution, they told me that it is a native Android issue.